Why is my basic Gekko ODE solver much slower than Scipy?
In this minimal example I want to solve the basic integrator ODE dT/dt = k[F(t) - T(t)] where F(t) is a forcing vector, which is selected to be a square wave. I have implemented two procedures to solve the ODE: Using Scipy's solve_ivp and using Gekko. The former takes 6 milliseconds to run, the latter takes 8 seconds to run. Am I doing something wrong with Gekko? Are there some additional parameters that I can tune to improve performance?
I have omitted the testing part of the code, but I have compared both solutions to the analytic solution, and they are both accurate within a 3-4 significant digits.
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
from gekko import GEKKO

def step_problem_forcing(time_arr, param):
    T_low = param['T_low']
    T_high = param['T_high']
    t_break_l = param['t_break_l']
    t_break_r = param['t_break_r']

    forcing = np.full(len(time_arr), T_low)
    idxs_pulse = np.logical_and(time_arr >= t_break_l,
                                time_arr <= t_break_r)
    forcing[idxs_pulse] = T_high
    return forcing

def step_problem_generate(tmin, tmax):
    tAvg = (tmin+tmax) / 2
    tDur = tmax - tmin
    return {
        'k' : 10 ** np.random.uniform(-3, 3),
        'T_low' : np.random.uniform(20, 50),
        'T_high' : np.random.uniform(20, 50),
        'T0' : np.random.uniform(20, 50),
        't_break_l' : np.random.uniform(tmin, tAvg - 0.1*tDur),
        't_break_r' : np.random.uniform(tAvg + 0.1*tDur, tmax)
    }

def ode_scipy_step_solver(time_arr, param: dict):
    f_this = lambda t: np.interp(t, time_arr, param['forcing'])
    
    def _dxdt(t, x, param: tuple):
        # if (t < tmin) or (t > tmax):
        #     raise ValueError(f"{t} is out of bounds [{tmin}, {tmax}]")
        k, = param
        return k*(f_this(t) - x)
    
    k = param['k']
    sol = solve_ivp(_dxdt, (time_arr[0], time_arr[-1]),
                    [param['T0'], ], t_eval=time_arr, args=([k, ],),
                    rtol=1.0E-6, method='RK45')
    return sol['y'].T

def  ode_gekko_step_solver(time_arr, param: dict) -> np.ndarray:
    m = GEKKO()  # create GEKKO model

    # Define variables
    m.time = time_arr
    T = m.Var(value=param['T0'])
    F = m.Param(value=param['forcing'])
    k = m.Const(value=param['k'])
    # t = m.Param(value=m.time)

    # equations
    m.Equation(T.dt() == k * (F - T))
    m.options.IMODE = 7  # dynamic simulation
    m.solve(disp=False)  # solve locally (remote=False)

    return T.value

tmin = 0
tmax = 10
time_arr = np.linspace(tmin, tmax, 1000)
param = step_problem_generate(tmin, tmax)
param['forcing'] = step_problem_forcing(time_arr, param)

# Takes 6.8ms to run
rezScipy = ode_scipy_step_solver(time_arr, param)

# Takes 8.5s to run
rezGekko = ode_gekko_step_solver(time_arr, param)


Switch to remote=False to solve locally and avoid the overhead due to network communication to the public server. Switching to IMODE=4 solves all 1000 time steps simultaneously instead of sequentially and can improve solve time. Here are 10 trials with the 1 original and 9 modified versions. I'm on Ubuntu Linux. Timing will likely be different based on the computer.
# IMODE=7, Original Script
ODE Scipy Time: 0.014239072799682617
Gekko Time: 8.92684006690979

# IMODE=4, Remote=False
ODE Scipy Time: 0.2553427219390869
Gekko Time: 0.12177252769470215

ODE Scipy Time: 0.0017511844635009766
Gekko Time: 0.11760997772216797

ODE Scipy Time: 0.0032286643981933594
Gekko Time: 0.11528849601745605

ODE Scipy Time: 0.06327152252197266
Gekko Time: 0.12140154838562012

ODE Scipy Time: 0.01037144660949707
Gekko Time: 0.12077593803405762

ODE Scipy Time: 0.0036330223083496094
Gekko Time: 0.11592268943786621

ODE Scipy Time: 0.1100163459777832
Gekko Time: 0.11649894714355469

ODE Scipy Time: 0.0032815933227539062
Gekko Time: 0.1154778003692627

ODE Scipy Time: 0.0015087127685546875
Gekko Time: 0.1158149242401123

Here's the modified script:
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
from gekko import GEKKO
import time

def step_problem_forcing(time_arr, param):
    T_low = param['T_low']
    T_high = param['T_high']
    t_break_l = param['t_break_l']
    t_break_r = param['t_break_r']

    forcing = np.full(len(time_arr), T_low)
    idxs_pulse = np.logical_and(time_arr >= t_break_l,
                                time_arr <= t_break_r)
    forcing[idxs_pulse] = T_high
    return forcing

def step_problem_generate(tmin, tmax):
    tAvg = (tmin+tmax) / 2
    tDur = tmax - tmin
    return {
        'k' : 10 ** np.random.uniform(-3, 3),
        'T_low' : np.random.uniform(20, 50),
        'T_high' : np.random.uniform(20, 50),
        'T0' : np.random.uniform(20, 50),
        't_break_l' : np.random.uniform(tmin, tAvg - 0.1*tDur),
        't_break_r' : np.random.uniform(tAvg + 0.1*tDur, tmax)
    }

def ode_scipy_step_solver(time_arr, param: dict):
    f_this = lambda t: np.interp(t, time_arr, param['forcing'])
    
    def _dxdt(t, x, param: tuple):
        # if (t < tmin) or (t > tmax):
        #     raise ValueError(f"{t} is out of bounds [{tmin}, {tmax}]")
        k, = param
        return k*(f_this(t) - x)
    
    k = param['k']
    sol = solve_ivp(_dxdt, (time_arr[0], time_arr[-1]),
                    [param['T0'], ], t_eval=time_arr, args=([k, ],),
                    rtol=1.0E-6, method='RK45')
    return sol['y'].T

def  ode_gekko_step_solver(time_arr, param: dict) -> np.ndarray:
    m = GEKKO(remote=False)  # create GEKKO model

    # Define variables
    m.time = time_arr
    T = m.Var(value=param['T0'])
    F = m.Param(value=param['forcing'])
    k = m.Const(value=param['k'])
    # t = m.Param(value=m.time)

    # equations
    m.Equation(T.dt() == k * (F - T))
    m.options.IMODE = 4  # dynamic simulation
    m.solve(disp=False)  # solve locally (remote=False)

    return T.value

tmin = 0
tmax = 10
time_arr = np.linspace(tmin, tmax, 1000)
param = step_problem_generate(tmin, tmax)
param['forcing'] = step_problem_forcing(time_arr, param)

st = time.time()
rezScipy = ode_scipy_step_solver(time_arr, param)
print(f'ODE Scipy Time: {time.time()-st}')

st = time.time()
rezGekko = ode_gekko_step_solver(time_arr, param)
print(f'Gekko Time: {time.time()-st}')

Scipy solve_ivp is a specialized ODE solver while Gekko solves higher index DAEs, mixed integer optimization, regression, and machine learning models. It uses a simultaneous method and only has basic adaptive step lengths to control error. I recommend solve_ivp if it is an ODE problem.

Thanks a lot, this really helps! This minimal example only solves a basic ODE, but what we actually want is solving for parameters and controlling our ODEs, so Gekko would shine there I'm sure. I'm developing 3 different engines simultaneously (Scipy, Gekko, Neuromancer), because I don't have the intuition to foresee which one will be superior for the final product, and it matters. We care about speed, accuracy and resilience to local minima.

Interesting project. Here is additional information on open-source optimization tools: https://apm.byu.edu/prism/index.php/Projects/OpenSourceModeling
